# AWS Template Error? How to decode the error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am getting an AWS CFN error of `Template validation error: Template error: Mapping named 'com.amazonaws.aws21.digester.tokens.ParameterReferenceToken@57001ea' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template.` I doubled checked all the references to the mappings region.

Comment: Error is very clear, you have "mapping as value for parameter", but no mapping definition found in template. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/gettingstarted.templatebasics.html

Comment: what does "com.amazonaws.aws21.digester.tokens.ParameterReferenceToken@57001ea" even mean

Comment: That is the part of AWS code which validates your cloud formation template while creating stack. Your question should be, which parameter reference in my code causing this.